# Understanding uni- and termolecular reactions in combustion kinetics

Tags: kinetics, combustion

I'm trying to understand and incorporate 9-species 19-reaction H2/O2 combustion mechanism into my numerical solver. The reaction mechanism in question is [O'Conaire](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/kin.20036). It seems that the paper is in some standard chemical-kinetics-paper format and thus some basic things are omitted. I have no background in chemistry and after few hours of googling there are still several unclear things that I hope you could help me with.

It is probably illegal to reproduce significant part of the aforementioned paper, so I'll have to only refer some thing here.

So far I assume the following things:

1. The partial reaction rate for density of $i$-th gas component in $k$-th reaction can be calculated via Arrhenius and acting masses laws:
   $$
   \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\rho_i}{\mu_i}\right)_k = \omega_i = A T^n e^{\left(\frac{E_a}{RT}\right)}\left(\frac{\rho_1}{\mu_1}\right)^a\left(\frac{\rho_2}{\mu_2}\right)^b
   $$
   where $\mu_i$ is $i$-th component molar mass, $A$ is pre-exponent constant,  $T$ is absolute temperature, $n$ is temperature exponent and $E_a$ is activation energy; $\rho_1, \rho_2$ are densitites of relevant reactants. Division of densities by molar masses result in molar concentrations:
   $$
   \left[\rho_i\right] = \frac{kg}{m^3}, \quad \left[\mu_i\right] = \frac{kg}{mol}, \quad \left[\frac{\rho_i}{\mu_i}\right] = \frac{mol}{m^3}.
   $$
   For example, in the "$O+H_2 = H + OH$" reaction (number 2 in the [paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/kin.20036)), the rate for $H_2$ would be
   $$
   \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\rho_{H_2}}{\mu_{H_2}}\right) = -5.08 \times 10^4 T^{2.67} e^{\left(\frac{6.292}{RT}\right)}\left(\frac{\rho_O}{\mu_O}\right)\left(\frac{\rho_{H_2}}{\mu_{H_2}}\right).
   $$
   with proper units. The minus sign is due to that $H_2$ is consumed during this reaction.
2. All of the reactions given in the paper are considered elementary and thus exponents for molar concentrations all equal unity. Except maybe reactions like "$O + O + M = O_2 + M$" (see the questions 2, 4, 5 below).
3. For a particular gas component, final rate is the sum of all reaction rates that the component participate in, with "-" sign if it is consumed and with "+" sign if it is produced.

So, the questions are the following:

1. Are my assumptions correct?
2. What if there is there are two of the same molecule/atom in the left side of the reaction, what would the molar concetration exponent be? Is it just $1+1 = 2$?
3. What is the physical sense of negative $E_a$? Is it that participating radicals are so chemically active that the reaction would be very fast even at very low temperatures?
4. For reactions involving third bodies (denoted "M"), so called "efficiency factors" are provided. What are these?
5. How to properly take into account third body concentrations?
6. In an [older paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/(SICI)1097-4601(1999)31:2%3C113::AID-KIN5%3E3.0.CO;2-0), reactions with "M" are called pressure dependendent. Does that mean that all other reactions are considered independent of pressure?
7. What are the Troe parameters (given for reacxtion 9 and 15)
8. What do $k_O$ and $k_{\infty}$ in the older paper mean?
9. What would be the good textbook or article to read to understand these things better?

Comment: Access to the reference is expensive for those, like me, who are not really interested in this paper. And why not replace $\pu{\frac{\rho}{\mu}}$ by simply the concentration $c$ ?

Comment: Note that questions should be understandable standalone, without following any links. By other words, even if the links do not work. Links should be needed only for further, more detailed reading, for full context or as the source reference.